# What is the derivative of digamma function?

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, statistical-inference, gamma-function

I want to know $(\frac{\Gamma'(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)})'$. My goal is to show $\alpha $ times this derivative of digamma is greater than 1.

The background of question is to show $\bar{x}$ is not asymptotically efficient for Gamma($\alpha$,1), because the ratio of Var$\bar{x}$ and Cramer-Rao Lower Bound is greater than 1. I can show that this ratio is $\alpha $ times this derivative of digamma. But I don't know how to show it is >1.

Comment: That would be the first order [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Comment: Explore the trigamma function $\psi_1$. The fact that $\psi_1(z) = \sum_k^\infty (z + n^2)^{-1}$ might prove helpful in your bounding below.

Comment: Yes, I can find the derivative of digamma (a.k.a trigamma function) is Var(logW), where W ~ Gamma($\alpha$,1). What's the next step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that by definition of the [polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) function:
$$
\alpha \partial_\alpha\frac{\Gamma^\prime(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=\alpha \partial_\alpha^2\log\Gamma(\alpha)=\alpha\psi^{(1)}(\alpha).
$$
Now calling on [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Inequalities) detailing inequalities of polygamma functions we find for all $\alpha>0$:
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}\leq\psi^{(1)}(\alpha)\leq \frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}.
$$
Multiplying the entire inequality by $\alpha$ and only considering the lower bound then gives
$$
\alpha\psi^{(1)}(\alpha)\geq1+\frac{1}{2\alpha}>1,
$$
which is the desired result.